# Read LTE RSRQ SNR in Android

Tags: android

I am writing an app that reads the RSRQ and SNR of the serving LTE network. I am currently using the `onSignalStrengthsChanged()` in `PhoneStateListener` in order to read the network measurements every time it updates. However, the update rate is very slow (every 4-5 seconds). So I am wondering if there is another way to read the network RSRQ and SNR measurements at a faster rate, or if there is a way to force the `onSignalStrengthsChanged()` to update at a faster rate (every 1 second).

Answer (score 0):

There's a reason it's called `onSignalStrengthsChanged` ... as it only gets called when they have changed, so you can assume that the values haven't changed until you get the next update.

Comment: That's my explanation first, but when I read  some LTE documentation, I found that the mobile measures these every 10 ms. Secondly, If we think about it, it is impossible that the readings remain the same for 4-5 seconds because the RF channel is very dynamic and the measurements should change at a much faster pace.